# C# TreeView Child Node Count .. Like Outlook

Tags: c#, treeview

In C# 2.0 does anyone know how to display the count of children nodes like Outlook does with unread emails. Also, if the count displayed can be in a different color to the node text.

Has anyone achieved this with "Safe" code?

Answer (score 3):

In order to display a string with more than one color you'd have to do custom GDI drawing in the treeview.  Here's a chapter on how to do OwnerDrawn controls:

http://books.google.com/books?id=zDi4LIDvd4wC&pg=PA396&lpg=PA396&dq=treeview+ownerdrawn&source=web&ots=hJIvexSusO&sig=XR8-ktfgllcjFmGs0FSfP0HYqIc&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=5&ct=result#PPA398,M1

Comment: That is a great book.  I was always using it when I used to be in WinForms land.  The chapter on printing really saved me on a project.

Answer (score -1):

inherit from the treeview control then change it to suit your needs